# BABL: Recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4

Tags: 11.04, gimp

I am trying to install the development version gimp2.7.2 on my Ubuntu 11.04 box.I was following [these instructions](http://www.gimpusers.com/tutorials/compiling-gimp-for-ubuntu) for the same.I ran into an error at the step where I had to make babl.

```
sudo make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abc/gimp2.7/gimp-2.7.2/babl'
Making all in babl
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/gimp2.7/gimp-2.7.2/babl/babl'
Making all in base
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/gimp2.7/gimp-2.7.2/babl/babl/base'
  CC     babl-base.lo
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4 Debian-2.4-2, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.2.6b.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4 Debian-2.4-2
libtool: and run autoconf again.
make[3]: *** [babl-base.lo] Error 63
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/gimp2.7/gimp-2.7.2/babl/babl/base'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/gimp2.7/gimp-2.7.2/babl/babl'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/gimp2.7/gimp-2.7.2/babl'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The error line is

```
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4 Debian-2.4-2,but the 
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.2.6b.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4 Debian-2.4-2
libtool: and run autoconf again.
```

How do I recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running

```
autoreconf 
./configure
make
```

in the root directory of your project.

If that doesn't work, try running `make maintainer-clean` first and then go to step 1.

If that still doesn't work, run `make maintainer-clean`, then delete every generated file in the root directory of your project; including `aclocal.m4`, any `m4` directory, any `autom4te.cache` directory, `configure`, `Makefile.in`, `config.h`, `config.h.in`, `config.status`, `libtool`, `ltmain.sh`, etc. Then go to step 1.

From user [mspoerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63520/mspoerr) over at our friends at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096989/libtool-version-mismatch-error).

Comment: did that. thanks. However I am stuck at the next step. even after instal babl, the gimp configure step says. No package 'babl' found. Guess that is for another question.

Comment: yes that's the general idea of AU ;)

Answer (score 2):

In Gentoo this works:

```
$ phpize 
$ aclocal && libtoolize --force && autoreconf
$ ./configure bbbb#again
```

Might work in Ubuntu too.

Comment: Are you suggesting that this might be helpful for Ubuntu users as well? If so, I recommend editing your answer to state that, and possibly also to explain why. If, on the other hand, you don't think this would help people who are running Ubuntu rather than Gentoo, then this is probably not suitable as an answer for this Ask Ubuntu question.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and the solution was very simple:

Just export the anvironment variable `BABL_CFLAGS` with the path where is the installation of *babl*. In my case, I used:

```
export BABL_CFLAGS=/opt/babl-0.1.10
```

Just put your own *babl* path installation and it's gonna work fine for you!