# Installing GIMP 2.8 from source on a system with GIMP 2.10 , babl library not found

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gimp

My 18.04 system has GIMP 2.10 installed. I need to use a plugin that will only work with GIMP 2.8. On the gimp.org [Old Stable Downloads](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/oldstable/) page they advise installing a Flatpak of it, but that wanted to install the new version so I didn't do it. That left installing from source.

I am a pretty simple user, but I found [How-to Geek's](https://www.howtogeek.com/105413/how-to-compile-and-install-from-source-on-ubuntu/) guide to installing from source, downloaded the tar.bz2, and began. There are other programs on my computer that have two different versions that co-exist fine so I didn't think about that. I extracted the tar.bz2 in my Downloads directory and ran ./configure from there.

The configure process stopped when it couldn't find the babl library. I downloaded babl and compiled it from source, and that seemed to complete fine, its directory is now set up in usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. However, the configure process for GIMP 2.8 still says it can't find it.

I found this question here, which is 8 years old now - [Installed babl, but gimp2.7 still says No package 'babl' found](https://askubuntu.com/q/56969/364597)

The solution won't work for me as it was a different install process. It got me concerned that the install might have or cause problems because of the presence of 2.10. And also I don't know how to resolve the issue of the babl library.

Help?

Comment: Why did you build BABL from source - rather than installing `libbabl-dev` using `apt`?

Comment: @steeldriver Ah - i must have used the wrong name when i searched for the package - i didn't find that. Okay, that worked - thank you :) One more package to go.

Comment: You will have to do the same with GEGL :)

Comment: What plugin is that, by the way?